# unity - intecepting class calls with several interfaces

Tags: unity-container

i have this code

```
public interface Interfcae1
    {
        void OP1();
    }

    public interface Interfcae2
    {
        void OP2();
    }

    public interface Interfcae3
    {
        void OP3();
    }

    public class Multi : Interfcae1, Interfcae2, Interfcae3
    {
        public void OP1()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        public void OP2()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
        }

        public void OP3()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);
        }
    }
```

i want to use unity to intercept all the function calls to test how much time it take for each call.

my main code is

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
container.RegisterType<Interfcae1, Multi>(
                        // new InjectionConstructor(typeof(string)),
                         new Interceptor<TransparentProxyInterceptor>(),
                         new InterceptionBehavior<InterceptBehavior>());
container.RegisterType<Interfcae2, Multi>(
                // new InjectionConstructor(typeof(string)),
                         new Interceptor<TransparentProxyInterceptor>(),
                         new InterceptionBehavior<InterceptBehavior>());
container.RegisterType<Interfcae2, Multi>(
                // new InjectionConstructor(typeof(string)),
                         new Interceptor<TransparentProxyInterceptor>(),
                         new InterceptionBehavior<InterceptBehavior>());

var proxy = container.Resolve<Multi>();
```

but at the resolve i am getting exception that the type is not interceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to `Configure`?

```
var intp = container.Configure<Interception>()
    .SetInterceptorFor(qualifiedType, new TransparentProxyInterceptor());
```

After that, do an `AddPolicy` and you should be good to go... Remember to specify the type info for the interface to intercept, and the interception handler.

```
var policy = intp.AddPolicy("myFirstInterception");
policy.AddMatchingRule<TypeMatchingRule>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new InjectionParameter(typeof(Interface1))))
            .AddCallHandler(typeof(MyInterceptionHandler), 
                new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Also try modifying the `Multi` class definition as:

```
public class Multi : MarshalByRefObject, Interfcae1, Interfcae2, Interfcae3
```

Comment: i have added this line  var intp = container.Configure<Interception>().SetInterceptorFor(typeof(Multi), new TransparentProxyInterceptor()); and got exception --> The type ConsoleApplication1.Multi is not interceptable.
Parameter name: typeToIntercept

Comment: Add `MarshalByRefObject` to the Multi class.

Comment: this project is a test project, i want to test timing on my wcf proxy class

Comment: What exactly is the interception handler in this example?

Comment: @Jan: that would be the `MyInterceptionHandler`.

Comment: @code4life: yes of course it would be, but the person asking is obviously using `InterceptBehavior` and *not* `ICallHandler`, so I was wondering how you came from one to the other.